# How to allow an app to adapt to different screen widths automatically

Tags: android, layout, android-screen-support

I did a bit of digging into [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes), but was not able to get any solution to work.

**My problem:**
I have a header layout that is included in all my screens. And depending on the width of the screen, I want to show one of three different header layouts. Sidenote; my app only supports portrait mode.

My layouts are:

- [Image] [Button][Text] [Button][Text] --> for big screens
- [Image] [Button][Text] [Button] --> for medium screens
- [Image] [Button] [Button] --> for small screens

And they should be chosen automatically by the app depending on the screen width. I want to get around doing this programatically because I would need to do this pretty much in every activity, so would be nice if this could be done correct so that the system can handle it.

**I tried (but didn't work):**

- Putting the three different layouts in 3 different folders called "layout", "layout-sw320dp", "layout-sw400dp"
- Putting the three different layouts in 3 different folders called "layout", "layout-xxhdpi", "layout-xxxhdpi"

Thanks a lot for your answers in advance!

**Edit:**
The layout looks actually a bit more complicated that described here. The actual layout is the following:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <RelativeLayout>
     <ImageView />
     <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
           <ImageView />
           <TextView />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
           <ImageView />
           <TextView />
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Also the image inside the first ImageView is loaded from the internet and I don't know its size before it has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this layout for you. You only need to create one XML file and place the items in this container. Set the importance of the elements. Items with low importance will be remowed (GONE) if there is not enough space. Please tell me if you need something to supplement or change. On my device it works.

Example

```
<com.sup.dev.android.views.widgets.layouts.LayoutImportance
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_700"
        android:text="text_1"
        app:LayoutImportance_Layout_importance="5"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue_700"
        app:LayoutImportance_Layout_importance="1"
        android:text="teeeeeeeeext_2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green_700"
        app:LayoutImportance_Layout_importance="2"
        android:text="teeeeeeeeext_3_teeeeext"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/amber_700"
        app:LayoutImportance_Layout_importance="3"
        android:text="teeeeeeeeext_4_teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext"/>

</com.sup.dev.android.views.widgets.layouts.LayoutImportance>
```

LayoutImportance.java

```
public class LayoutImportance extends LinearLayout {

private int lock;

public LayoutImportance(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    if (lock == 0) for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) getChildAt(i).setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), heightMeasureSpec);

    if (getMeasuredWidth() > w) {

        ArrayList<View> children = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) if (getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == VISIBLE) children.add(getChildAt(i));
        if(children.isEmpty())return;

        Collections.sort(children, (o1, o2) -> ((LayoutParams) o1.getLayoutParams()).importance - ((LayoutParams) o2.getLayoutParams()).importance);
        children.get(0).setVisibility(GONE);

        lock++;
        onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        lock--;
    }

}

@Override
protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return p instanceof LayoutParams;
}

@Override
protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(getContext(), null);
}

@Override
public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
}

@Override
protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
}


public static class LayoutParams extends LinearLayout.LayoutParams {

    public int importance;

    public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LayoutImportance_Layout);
        importance = a.getInt(R.styleable.LayoutImportance_Layout_LayoutImportance_Layout_importance, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
        super(w, h);
    }

}
```

}

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="LayoutImportance_Layout">
    <attr name="LayoutImportance_Layout_importance" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot! But I have two issues with it: 1. I don't have a simple list of elements in my header, this was only to simplify the the problem. I actually have multiple layouts and stuff in there and I would need to hide one or texts if needed. I will add this to my initial question. 2. I have an image in the header which is loaded from the web, so I don't know the size of the image until I got it...

Comment: Alright, I tweaked your solution a little for my needs and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to get the layout width of your each header and make different layouts for each header.then check the screen size programatically and before inflating the layout you would have to set the header respected to your width.

Use this code to get the width of device:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

and then

```
if(width==smallDevice){   //or whatever condition you want
setHeaderLayoutFor("smallDevice");
}

else if(width=="mediumDevice"){
setHeaderLayoutFor("mediumDevice");
}
else if(width=="largerDevice"){
setHeaderLayoutFor("largeDevice");
}
```

and make setHeaderLayoutFor(String layoutType) to set/inflate the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Scalable dp"(sdp). This size unit scales with the screen size.

To add sdp to your project (Using Android Studio and Gradle):

add **implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'** to your build.gradle dependencies block.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
}
```

Design your xml as shown below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_main_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_27sdp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_43sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_43sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_50sdp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Intuit"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_minus10sdp"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:includeFontPadding="false"
                            android:text="♡"
                            android:textColor="#ED6C27"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:includeFontPadding="false"
                            android:text="U"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_text_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="Rate us so we can grow and help more people get their finances in check"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_text_2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="★★★★★"
                            android:textColor="#747474"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_button"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                            android:text="Rate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:minWidth="120dp"
                            android:includeFontPadding="false"
                            android:background="#0ac775"
                            android:singleLine="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Check the link for more information: https://github.com/intuit/sdp